# read Asp.Net Web api GET values from url

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to map `/{Controller}/{Variable1}/{Variable2}/{Variable3}` to a GET method in controller

```
public TestController{

public ActionResult Get([FromUrl] Entity instance){}

}
```

So I need to map variables to the entity.

To put it into an example

> /Product/{category}/{filter1}/{filter2}/

Entity

```
 public class ProductSearchRequest
{ 
       public string Category{get;set;}   
       public string filter1 {get;set;}
       public string filter2 {get;set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public ProductController: Controller {
public ActionResult GET([FromUri] ProductSearchRequest productSearchRequest){

}

}
```

**[EDITED]**

Had to do following changes to get this working

Instead of RouteCollection.MapHttpRoute use HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute as this is API routing not MVC routing.

Inherit controller from ApiController rather than Controller which I was before.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not going to be able to do that. Complex types are not compatible with the routing mechanism.

Take a read of [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) article. But this paragraph explains why the routing mechanism cannot do what you are asking.

> A complex type can only bind to the URI through a custom binding. But
>   in that case, the framework cannot know in advance whether the
>   parameter would bind to a particular URI. To find out, it would need
>   to invoke the binding. The goal of the selection algorithm is to
>   select an action from the static description, before invoking any
>   bindings. Therefore, complex types are excluded from the matching
>   algorithm.

Therefore the basic rule is:

> For every parameter of the action, if the parameter is taken from the
>   URI, then the parameter name must be found either in the route
>   dictionary or in the URI query string. (Optional parameters and
>   parameters with complex types are excluded.)

Which means you need to define your action like so:

```
public ActionResult GET(string Category, string filter1, string filter2){
}
```

And your route template:

```
/{controller}/{category}/{filter1}/{filter2}/
```